# Python, Kivy: Building an Android Package (.apk)

Tags: android, python, windows, kivy

As the title says, I'm trying to build an Android Package (.apk / App) using Python and Kivy. I've got no idea how to convert .py to .apk or if it's even possible like this. So my questions are:

- What programs do I need, to turn my .py files into .apk s?
- How do I install these programs? (Sometimes a little bit difficult with python modules etc.)
- How do I use these programs to do it?
- Will it work on Windows? (As I'm using Windows, that's my main question :/ )

Thank you for hopefully coming answers :)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) to get the feet wet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Kivy documentation [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) and [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html).

You cannot currently use these tools on windows, but you can use a linux virtual machine. This is explained in the above documentation.